# Different output than expected when running python -v

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, python-3.7

Installed Python 3.7.3 on my W10 machine and wanted to ensure it was already installed.

In order to do it, when to the command prompt and ran the following command

```
python -v
```

The output was not what i was expecting...

```
import _frozen_importlib # frozen
import _imp # builtin
import '_thread' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_warnings' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_weakref' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# installing zipimport hook
import 'zipimport' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# installed zipimport hook
import '_frozen_importlib_external' # <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>
import '_io' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'marshal' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'nt' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import _thread # previously loaded ('_thread')
import '_thread' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import _weakref # previously loaded ('_weakref')
import '_weakref' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'winreg' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\encodings\__pycache__\__init__.cpython-37.pyc matches C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\encodings\__init__.py
# code object from 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\lib\\encodings\\__pycache__\\__init__.cpython-37.pyc'
# C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\__pycache__\codecs.cpython-37.pyc matches C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\codecs.py
# code object from 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\lib\\__pycache__\\codecs.cpython-37.pyc'
import '_codecs' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'codecs' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x0000014FACF251D0>
# C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\encodings\__pycache__\aliases.cpython-37.pyc matches C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\encodings\aliases.py
# code object from 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\lib\\encodings\\__pycache__\\aliases.cpython-37.pyc'
import 'encodings.aliases' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x0000014FACF3BCF8>
import 'encodings' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x0000014FACF19588>
# C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\encodings\__pycache__\utf_8.cpython-37.pyc matches C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\encodings\utf_8.py
# code object from 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\lib\\encodings\\__pycache__\\utf_8.cpython-37.pyc'
import 'encodings.utf_8' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x0000014FACF4BDA0>
import '_signal' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\encodings\__pycache__\latin_1.cpython-37.pyc matches C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\encodings\latin_1.py
# code object from 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\lib\\encodings\\__pycache__\\latin_1.cpython-37.pyc'
import 'encodings.latin_1' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x0000014FACF4F208>
# C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\__pycache__\io.cpython-37.pyc matches C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\io.py
# code object from 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\lib\\__pycache__\\io.cpython-37.pyc'
# C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\__pycache__\abc.cpython-37.pyc matches C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\abc.py
# code object from 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\lib\\__pycache__\\abc.cpython-37.pyc'
import '_abc' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'abc' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x0000014FACF4F7B8>
import 'io' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x0000014FACF4F400>
# C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\__pycache__\site.cpython-37.pyc matches C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site.py
# code object from 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\lib\\__pycache__\\site.cpython-37.pyc'
# C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\__pycache__\os.cpython-37.pyc matches C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\os.py
# code object from 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\lib\\__pycache__\\os.cpython-37.pyc'
# C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\__pycache__\stat.cpython-37.pyc matches C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\stat.py
# code object from 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\lib\\__pycache__\\stat.cpython-37.pyc'
import '_stat' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'stat' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x0000014FAEBC9A58>
# C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\__pycache__\ntpath.cpython-37.pyc matches C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\ntpath.py
# code object from 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\lib\\__pycache__\\ntpath.cpython-37.pyc'
# C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\__pycache__\genericpath.cpython-37.pyc matches C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\genericpath.py
# code object from 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\lib\\__pycache__\\genericpath.cpython-37.pyc'
import 'genericpath' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x0000014FAEBD6908>
import 'ntpath' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x0000014FAEBD0128>
# C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\__pycache__\_collections_abc.cpython-37.pyc matches C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\_collections_abc.py
# code object from 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\lib\\__pycache__\\_collections_abc.cpython-37.pyc'
import '_collections_abc' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x0000014FAEBD6EF0>
import 'os' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x0000014FACF5F668>
# C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\__pycache__\_sitebuiltins.cpython-37.pyc matches C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\_sitebuiltins.py
# code object from 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\lib\\__pycache__\\_sitebuiltins.cpython-37.pyc'
import '_sitebuiltins' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x0000014FACF5FA20>
import 'site' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x0000014FACF532B0>
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
import 'atexit' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
>>>
```

Well, it's possible to read the version in the 4th line counting from the bottom. Still, why it didn't just show the version?

Comment: run `python --help` to see descriptions for options

Comment: RTFM:  https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html) I see that worked as it should.

**-v** (lower case) means [verbose](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/153824/152750). This is going to tell you everything about what is doing all the time.

**-V** (upper case) means version. This is going to tell you the version.

So, to see the version I had to write

```
python -V
```

or

```
py -v
```

or

```
python --version
```

or

```
py --version
```

and I then got the following output

> Python 3.7.3

Comment: Also there is now (from 3.6)  the `-VV`